# Microsoft Azure Security rules - port blocking

Tags: azure

I am looking for the parallel service in Microsoft Azure Cloud for AWS's Security Groups,

Where can i define which ports are are open and which are closed for my instances and web roles ?

Where can i define my affinity group to open ports for specific IP's ?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681799/aws-security-groups-equivalent-in-azure